# Is there a user-level foolproof way to force termination of sshfs connections?

Tags: mount, sshfs, fuse

I want `sshfs` connections to be terminated after some time, an hour at the maximum, and this means launching the `at` command with `fusermount -u` in the same command or script that I use to launch the `sshfs` mount.

However I notice that the `fusermount` can fail if the files are in use, although I want the `at` command to work whether there are files still opened in the connection or not.

In my experience the only reliable way is to run the `fusermount` commands as root or terminate the `sshfs` connection via the `kill` command.

Is there some other way to force a disconnection without being running as root? The problem is I may not be at the terminal when the files are still open, but for the sake of security the connection must be broken unless I cancel the `at` command.

Comment: You can create a wrapper script on the server side, which will disconnect after the expected time (give that the `sshfs` will not try to reconnect after the connection gets closed -- need to try that out).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want to free up the mount point, and don't care about terminating the SSH connection, you can run `fusermount -z /mount/point`. This performs a lazy unmount: the mount point is no longer associated with the mount, but the mount doesn't disappear until all open files on that mount are closed.

If you only want to close the SSH connection and don't care about the mount, you can simply kill the SFTP server process. That's the beauty of FUSE: kill the process offering the service and it's gone. A mount can't lock up a system resource. The processes that try to access the filesystems will get an error (ENOTCONN ”Transport endpoint is not connected”).

If you want to kill the processes that have files open on that filesystem, you can use the [`fuser`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_(Unix)) command (no relation with FUSE except for the F being the first letter of “file”).

```
fuser -k /mount/point
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: I had to use `fusermount -zu /mount/point`, otherwise I got "fusermount: -z can only be used with -u".